# XAML GridView, ObservableCollection and changing an item's properties

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, observablecollection

I have a class, derived from BindableBase, which contains two properties:

```
    private string sourceCallNumber;
    public string SourceCallNumber
    {
        get { return sourceCallNumber; }
        set { SetProperty(ref sourceCallNumber, value); }
    }

    private string sourceMediaType;
    public string SourceMediaType
    {
        get { return sourceMediaType; }
        set { SetProperty(ref sourceMediaType, value); }
    }
```

I have an ObservableCollection that contains a number of items using that class.

I have a GridView for which I set the ItemsSource to point to the ObservableCollection.

My problem is that if I change the value of, say, SourceMediaType on one of the items, the display does not update. I have put debugging in and can confirm that changing the value causes OnPropertyChanged to fire for that property.

I've read quite a few SO questions and answers around similar problems and I'm getting quite confused as to what I need to do in order to get this to work.

My understanding was that although ObservableCollection itself doesn't do anything when a property is changed, if the item itself triggers an OnPropertyChanged, that should get the display to update.

(There was one answer I read that proposed the use of code provided called TrulyObservableCollection but the problem I've got there is that everything refreshes rather than just the one item that has been updated).

What am I missing or misunderstanding, please?

Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the way you explained. Are you sure that the Binding is not OneTime? Could you add the Xaml code as well?

Comment: I'll take a wild leap here, in your SetProperty function, shouldn't you pass a string representing the actual property being changed? Unless you get the property name from the field name (which would require all to follow the same pattern).

Comment: @Reza - no, the binding isn't OneTime.

Comment: @RodrigoSilva You were on the right path. SetProperty does indeed get the property name from the field name ... but that isn't what the XAML was binding to. The XAML was binding to a different property that put some formatting around the text. Explicitly mentioning that name cured the problem. I need to be smarter with my XAML and use converters rather than different properties.

Answer (score 0):

C# apps should implement INotifyCollectionChanged and System.Collections.IList (not IList Of T).

```
public class NameList : ObservableCollection<PersonName>
{
    public NameList() : base()
    {
        Add(new PersonName("Willa", "Cather"));
        Add(new PersonName("Isak", "Dinesen"));
        Add(new PersonName("Victor", "Hugo"));
        Add(new PersonName("Jules", "Verne"));
    }
  }

  public class PersonName
  {
      private string firstName;
      private string lastName;

      public PersonName(string first, string last)
      {
          firstName = first;
          lastName = last;
      }

      public string FirstName
      {
          get { return firstName; }
          set { firstName = value; }
      }

      public string LastName
      {
          get { return lastName; }
          set { lastName = value; }
      }
  }
```

Look at [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview.Aspx).

Comment: While you are correct that INotifyCollectionChanged needs to be implemented, ObservableCollection<T> does do this. Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464965.Aspx (under Binding a control to a collection of objects).

Answer (score 0):

@RodrigoSilva put me on the correct path ... the XAML that references the values was this:

```
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayCallNumber}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Visibility="{Binding GotCallNumber, Converter={StaticResource DisplayIfTrue}}" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayMediaType}" Style="{StaticResource ItemTextStyle}" Visibility="{Binding GotMediaType, Converter={StaticResource DisplayIfTrue}}" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

which doesn't directly reference the underlying properties SourceCallNumber and SourceMediaType. As a result, although OnPropertyChanged is correctly firing for SourceCallNumber and SourceMediaType, that isn't causing the display to update because that isn't what the XAML is pointing at.

Explicitly changing the call to SetProperty to this:

```
SetProperty(ref sourceCallNumber, value, "DisplayCallNumber");
```

fixes the problem but is not a GOOD fix because some other part of the app may actually be binding to SourceCallNumber and won't get a property update after this change. The GOOD fix is to use a converter as explained in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464965.aspx.